# How to make a javascript active just on the second visit on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm a great fan of stack overflow but this is the first time I have to write!

I have a page with a sort of drop-right menu opened when you click on the company logo. It is developed in straight css.
I've used this script to keep the menu opened while you navigate through the internal pages like "about", "gallery", "contacts", ecc...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slide").click();
});
</script>
```

What I need is to set this script activated on the home page just when you come back on it from other internal pages I told you before. And not on the first homepage load where I need the logo closed with the menu hided by its!

Anyone has some tips or suggestions please?
Thank you very much to everybody again!

Any other has a possible solution?

Comment: You can use cookies to make it happen or use local storage :)

Answer (score 2):

On the first visit, inside your document-ready clause:

```
localStorage.setItem("displayDropDown", "true");
```

On every visit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("displayDropDown") === "true") {
        $("#slide").click();
    }
});
```

Put them both in the same doc-ready clause:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("displayDropDown") === "true") {
        $("#slide").click();
    }
    localStorage.setItem("displayDropDown", "true");
});
```

Comment: Since the user is visiting the same page, you should have a single script, not two scripts. Make it a single block.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not so expert on javascript codes. What is localStorage? And where I have to put it? Straight between two <script></script>?

Comment: How can I make it in a single script block?

Comment: Just put both calls inside the same doc-ready block. This doesn't have to be two scripts, nor was I suggesting it should be.

Comment: Apparently it doesen't works. Home menu keeps to be closed both on first load and returning in it!

Comment: I really don't understand why... But it doesn't works... You were realy kind by the way!

Comment: This is my preview link: [link] awparma2.paginesi.it/sereni-dropright/index.html

Comment: @Darkan85 link syntax is `[link text](http://url)` - you're missing the protocol. I'll take a look at the page later on, and get back to you.

Comment: I'm a newbie on this website. Just a reader during past. I'm really sorry for eventually mistakes in using it.

Comment: @Darkan85 No worries, we were all newbies once, and I know how frustrating it can be. The [help] has a few articles which might help you understand the complex bits of the site.

Comment: I absolutely don't want to bother you! Any news?

Comment: @Darkan85 Yesterday didn't have enough hours in it! Hoping to have time tonight.

Comment: You're too kind! Thank you very much, for sure!

Comment: @Darkan85 Try that. I've updated it to use strings instead, since that's what the `getItem` call returns.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I appreciated so much! Unluckly the last modify has the only one effect to open up the dropright even in the home. But from the beginning. Instead I want it has to be opne just when you return into the home and not when you load the website for the first time!

Comment: @Darkan85 You're going to have to switch to doing this server-side.

Comment: I have to switch what?

Comment: @Darkan85 Talk to your back-end developers. You need to do this on the server-side, by adding a query string parameter when you return to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete example. It's using localStorange and Cookies (via [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)) as a fallback:

**Modern browser example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="count"></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const getNumberOfPreviousVisits = () => {
        const numberOfVisits = window.localStorage.numberOfVisits ? parseInt(window.localStorage.numberOfVisits, 10) + 1 : 0;

        window.localStorage.numberOfVisits = numberOfVisits;

        return numberOfVisits;
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        if (getNumberOfPreviousVisits() > 0) {
          // $("#slide").click();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Example, which supports legacy browsers:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="count"></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var localStorageAvailable = function() {
        try {
          var x = '__storage_test__';
          window.localStorage.setItem(x, x);
          window.localStorage.removeItem(x);
          return true;
        } catch(e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      var getNumberOfPreviousVisitsLocalStorage = function() {
        var numberOfVisits = window.localStorage.numberOfVisits ? parseInt(window.localStorage.numberOfVisits, 10) + 1 : 0;

        window.localStorage.numberOfVisits = numberOfVisits;

        return numberOfVisits;
      }

      var getNumberOfPreviousVisitsCookie = function() {
        var numberOfVisits = Cookies.get('numberOfVisits') ? parseInt(Cookies.get('numberOfVisits'), 10 ) + 1 : 0;

        Cookies.set('numberOfVisits', numberOfVisits);

        return numberOfVisits;
      }

      var getNumberOfPreviousVisits = function() {
        if (localStorageAvailable()) {
          return getNumberOfPreviousVisitsLocalStorage();
        }

        return getNumberOfPreviousVisitsCookie();
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        if (getNumberOfPreviousVisits() > 0) {
          // $("#slide").click();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Original example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="count"></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const localStorageAvailable = () => {
        try {
          const x = '__storage_test__';
          window.localStorage.setItem(x, x);
          window.localStorage.removeItem(x);
          return true;
        } catch(e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      const getNumberOfPreviousVisitsLocalStorage = () => {
        const numberOfVisits = window.localStorage.numberOfVisits ? parseInt(window.localStorage.numberOfVisits, 10) + 1 : 0;

        window.localStorage.numberOfVisits = numberOfVisits;

        return numberOfVisits;
      }

      const getNumberOfPreviousVisitsCookie = () => {
        const numberOfVisits = Cookies.get('numberOfVisits') ? parseInt(Cookies.get('numberOfVisits'), 10 ) + 1 : 0;

        Cookies.set('numberOfVisits', numberOfVisits);

        return numberOfVisits;
      }

      const getNumberOfPreviousVisits = () => {
        if (localStorageAvailable()) {
          return getNumberOfPreviousVisitsLocalStorage();
        }

        return getNumberOfPreviousVisitsCookie();
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        if (getNumberOfPreviousVisits() > 0) {
          // $("#slide").click();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that ES6? Bear in mind there are a number of current browsers that still don't support that. Otherwise, nice answer.

Comment: Yes … I noticed it after posting the example. Using a cookie fallback and ES2015 obviously is a bad idea

Comment: But where I have to set this code with my code parts to make it run?

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could just check if getNumberOfPreviousVisits() returns a number higher than zero inside your $(document).ready() callback